Unable to get if intent filter is handled by an installed mobile application from javascript
I have been given the task to update our website to check if our mobile application is installed.  If it is installed, ask if the user wants to open our mobile application.  If it is not installed, ask if the user wants to go to our mobile app page.  There is more around the logic here that does not apply (whether it's a good idea to do this, or how often, etc.).
I have implemented the intent filter on my android app, and I am able to successfully launch it from my site.  No problem there.
I am struggling on finding if there is an app that can handle the intent.  Included below is my code that I've gotten it to work but only when the commented out alert is in place.  This alert cannot be in place.  I have tried putting in delays/timeouts to set the iframe source thinking maybe the alert is causing some kind of timing issue.  I've tried onblur, visibility changes.
function OpenApp(isAppInstalled) {
    if (isAppInstalled) {
        var launchApp = confirm("Do you want to launch the mobile app?");
        if (launchApp) {
            window.location.href = "myintent://www.myintent.com";
        }
    } else {
        var launchApp = confirm("We have a mobile app available. Would you like to view more information on how to get it?");
        if (launchApp) {
            window.location.href = "https://linktomobileapp.com";
        }
    }
}

function isIntentFilterHandled(intentUrl) {
    var isAppChecked = false;
    var start = Date.now();

    // Create an iframe to attempt to open the app
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    // Function to clean up and call OpenApp only once
    function cleanUpAndCallApp(isAppInstalled) {
        if (!isAppChecked) {
            isAppChecked = true;
            OpenApp(isAppInstalled);
            document.removeEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);
            document.body.removeChild(iframe);
        }
    }

    // Handle visibility change
    function handleVisibilityChange() {
        if (document.hidden) {
            cleanUpAndCallApp(true);
        }
    }

    // Add event listener for visibility change
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);

    // Handle the onblur event
    window.onblur = function() {
        if (!isAppChecked) {
            cleanUpAndCallApp(true);
        }
    };

    // Set a timeout to check if the app was opened
    var delay = 2000; // 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        var elapsed = Date.now() - start;
        if (!isAppChecked) {
            cleanUpAndCallApp(false);
        }
    }, delay);

    // Attempt to open the app
    iframe.src = intentUrl;
    // alert("Iframe src set to: " + intentUrl); // Code works with this alert, does not without it
}

window.onload = function() {
    var intentUrl = 'myintent://www.myintent.com';
    isIntentFilterHandled(intentUrl);
};


"I have been given the task to update our website to check if our mobile application is installed" -- have you discussed this with your attorney? "No problem there" -- several prominent Web browsers, such as Samsung Internet and Firefox, do not support deeplinks by default. "I am struggling on finding if there is an app that can handle the intent" -- from the standpoint of privacy and security, this is a good thing. To flip it around, any browser that supports what you are seeking has a bug.

@CommonsWare then, what's your idea?  I understand your point.  I'm asking this community for help on a problem I'm having, not just critiques of the problem.  Do you have another idea?  I'm open.  I've seen reddit do this similarly.  How does reddit accomplish this?

"what's your idea?" -- my idea is to warn those who read this question, today or in the future, that what you are proposing carries risks that should be investigated. My idea is also to point out that at best you'll get false negatives, as your approach implies a browser that supports deeplinks, and not all browsers do by default. "How does reddit accomplish this?" -- I have no idea. If I ever investigate that, it will be to get Reddit to stop and to get browsers to fix their bugs.

@CommonsWare I figured out how to get this done.  I redirect to an intent that has a fallback for the google play store.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78551479/1397701

In order to get this accomplished, we can use an intent that directs to the play store with a fall back.
So, redirect here:
intent://www.linktomobileapp.com#Intent;scheme=myintent;package=com.myintent.mobile;S.browser_fallback_url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myintent.mobile;end
Literally use "intent://" at the beginning, don't put your value there.  I specified "myintent" for when it needs to be my actual intent value.
